# Special properties of subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

I have two statements I am not sure how to prove them:

(1) Every graph with $n=|V(G)|\ge 6$ and size $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor+1$ contains a 5-cycle $C_5$

(2) Every graph with $n=|V(G)|\ge 5$ and size $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor+2$ contains two trinagles with exactly one vertex in common.

I think the best way is prove it by induction. For the simple cases n=6 or n=5 it is obvious for both cases (can be verfied geometrically.)

I do not know how to proceed with the induction step, may you can help me with that. If there is an alternative way to prove this it would be also very interesting.

Comment: Sorry, $n$ is the nuber of vertices, see my edited post.I do not use any specific book, only lecture notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction step for first problem (everything else seems to be settled),
so we assume that the statement has been proven for all graphs with less than $n$ vertices.

Now let $G$ be a graph with $n$ vertices and size $e\geq\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor+1$.
The average degree is $\frac{2e}{n}$, so there is a vertex $v$ with degree $d(v)\leq\frac{2e}{n}$.

Now remove this vertex for the induction step.
The size of the new graph is $e'=e-d(v)$.

We need to prove that $e'=e-d(v)\geq \lfloor\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}\rfloor+1$.
Then the induction hypothesis gives us a 5-cycle in the new graph, which certainly is a 5-cycle in the larger graph.

Case 1: $n$ is even.

The righthand side evaluates to:
$\frac{(n-1)^2-1}{4}+1=\frac{n^2-2n+4}{4}=\frac{n^3-2n^2+4n}{4n}$.

For the lefthand side we have
$e'=e-d(v)\geq e-\frac{2e}{n}=e\frac{n-2}{n}\geq \frac{n-2}{n}(\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor+1)
=\frac{n-2}{n}(\frac{n^2}{4}+1)=\frac{n-2}{n}\frac{n^2+4}{4}
=\frac{n^3-2n^2+4n-8}{4n}=\frac{n^3-2n^2+4n}{4n}-\frac{8}{4n}$

$\frac{8}{4n}<1$ since $n>2$, and because the number of edges always is an integer
we may conclude that $e'\geq\frac{n^3-2n^2+4n}{4n}$.

Case 2: $n$ is odd.
I leave that one to you.

Comment: By the way, if you do not want to wait for the article, the second problem can be proven in this way as well, but you have to prove a few more small cases first: induction starts at 7 for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just one little question about the case where n is odd. I get $\frac{n^3-2n^2+5n}{4n}$ for the RHS and $e'\ge\frac{n^3-2n^2+3n-6}{4n}$ bis this is not bigger than the RHS, did I make any mistake?

Comment: No mistake. Now write $3n-6$ as $5n-(2n+6)$ and check when $\frac{2n+6}{4n}<1$

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I also have a similar question stackexchange, it would be great if you can take a short look at it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561666/if-vg-n-and-eg-fracn4-1-sqrt4n-3-then-g-contains-4-cycle

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, but I cannot find references on a proof of your first statement. As to second one, we proved it in our paper (B.V.Novikov, L.Yu.Polyakova, G.N Zholtkevich, 
*A decomposition of directed graphs*, Ukrainian Math. J., to appear); later I found it as an exercise in B.Bollobás, *Modern Graph Theory*, of course, without a proof.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have some link to your paper? I cannot find it. If you have any ideas to the first one it would be great.

Comment: @Alkibiades: The article is accepted for publication, it will appear. If you write me by e-mail, I will send it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the article, but in which part of your paper do you exactly prove the second result?

Comment: @Alkibiades In last part "Forbidden subgraphs".